# Auto move cursor into a random location on the webpage via JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple web page to auto move cursor into a random positions.
I've tried and got the console to show random data, but I can't see the cursor moving.

Can someone please give me some hint to go further?

Should I also look into CSS transition ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Auto Mouse Mover</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Auto Mouse Mover</h1>
    <p>This page automatically moves the mouse to a random location every 5 seconds.</p>

    <script>
      // Move the mouse to a random location
      function moveMouse() {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight);
        window.moveTo(x, y);
        
        console.log(x, y);
        
        
      }

      // Move the mouse every 5 seconds
      setInterval(moveMouse, 1000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't move the cursor with JS nor any web programming language, imagine all the security problems it would have.

Comment: Correct the mouse is a hardware input device and is always under the user's control. If it would, it would be a huge security risk and potentially look a user out of his own PC.